# image source not readable using image intervention laravel 7

Tags: laravel, image, upload

I'm try to upload a photo from a camera in chrome mobile, but i get an error image source not readable.

i got an error when i'm try to upload image from a camera in android, but when i'm try using an iphone to upload image from the camera, the image was successfully uploaded. my code like this, i'm ussing image intervention in Laravel 7

```
    $image = $request->file('foto');
    $image_name = str_replace(' ','_',$request->judul).'_'.time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $destinationPath = public_path('/assets/img/galang_dana');

    $resize_image = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
    $resize_image->fit(800, 500, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->upsize();
    })->save($destinationPath . '/' . $image_name);

     $destinationPath = public_path('/assets/img/galang_dana/resize');
     $image = $image->move($destinationPath, $image_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code it will save the photo to the destination and also resize the photo at the same time.

```
$image = Image::make(public_path('assets/img/galang_dana/resize' . time() . "." . 
request()->foto->getClientOriginalExtension()))->resize(800, 500);
$image->save();
```

You are using the fit method which will crop your photo but the resize method will resize the photo without cropping it.
It works for me all the time.